# Which is the inlet and which is the outlet?

Tags: chevrolet, equinox

[image]I am asking this for my dad. The image is supposed to represent a 2006 Chevrolet Equinox V6, and he wanted to know which pipe is the inlet and which is the outlet, as well as through which water (or something) should flow in and through which should water flow out.

Comment: I've no idea about that specific car, but normally cold water goes in at the bottom and hot comes out at the top, which is the way a "thermosyphon" works without needing a pump to circulate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume these are heater hoses attached to the heater core through the firewall. According to the internet, the output from the heater core would be the return line to the water pump. And the input to the heater core would be the line going from the intake manifold or cylinder head.

Input should be the top hose.